# Any way to copy a VALUE from XSD during XSLT (Schema Aware XSLT 2.0 ala Post-Schema-Validation Infoset))?

Tags: xml, xsd, transformation, xslt-2.0

I´m trying to copy an Attribute value from one element in the schema to the XSLT output.
I tried copy-of, and visited a lot of examples with schema-element but it seems only used for matching or copying whole node structures...

Summing up, I would like to take profit of the xslt xsd awareness for doing the equivalent of the Post-Schema-Validation Infosetway of assigning default values to attributes

**XML**

```
     <MyProject Val="wrongval">
```

**XSD**

```
     <xs:element name="MyProject">
       <xs:complexType>
         <xs:attribute name="Val" fixed="1234" />
       </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
```

**XSLT**

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:element name="MyProject">
          <xsl:attribute name="Val">**???=1234**</xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're nearly there. Given the following (unused) source document:

```
<MyProject Val="wrongval"/>
```

and the following schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

     <xs:element name="MyProject">
       <xs:complexType>
         <xs:attribute name="Val" fixed="1234" />
       </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

and the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:import-schema schema-location="test.xsd"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:element name="MyProject" validation="strict"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the transformation output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><MyProject Val="1234"/>
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer but I forget to say this was a simplified example of my problem. What happens if the xsd is for the output of xslt and not the input, and so the names have to be changed. Basically if the example is the same but the name for the MyProject element in data file was MyBusinessProject and everything else remains the same?

Comment: You can apply schema validation to either the input or the output, or even to intermediate structures created in the course of processing. In each case schema validation will add default values for attributes (and elements) that have them.

Comment: That's not working for me using Altova XMLSpy 2011... I get <MyProject/> without any default or fixed value.
Any hints?